# Speech recognition with timestampsfor subtitles Python

Tags: python-3.x, timestamp, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Im trying to create a program that can create subtitles from audio files of a show. I've used the speech_recognition library to capture the words and print them but cant figure out how to get timestamps so they could be lined up with whats being said.

This is my code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
audio = sr.AudioFile('audio2.wav')

with audio as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    audio_text = r.record(source)
    decoder = r.recognize_google(audio_text, language='es-AR', show_all=False)

    print('converting')
    print(decoder + '\n')
```

Comment: have you seen this link on speech_recognition Github issues?
https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/142#issuecomment-238061783